# ARIMA Model shows flatline on predictions

Tags: time-series, arima

I am learning time series for first time and trying it out on some kaggle datasets. For daily stock price predictions/weather prediction (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sumanthvrao/daily-climate-time-series-data/data). To keep it simple while learning, I did not do any big stats/visualizations. I used autoarima and got order and predicted using ARIMA model. But I always end up on a flat line. Why is it so?

```
m = ARIMA(train['meantemp'], order = (1,1,1))
fit_model = m.fit()

predictions = fit_model.predict(start=len(train), end=len(train) + len(test) - 1)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(test.index, test.meantemp, label = 'Test data')
plt.plot( predictions, label='Predictions', color='red', linestyle='--')
plt.title('ARIMA Model')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
```

The below graph is for climate prediction
[image]

This is for stock prediction
[image]

Can someone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the forum @AJA. For starters it looks like you're passing ints (len(train)) to the predict call when you probably want to pass datetimes. There may be other problems as well.